# Form Elements update in real-time in Firefox but in IE they don't

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer, firefox

Here's the code I have:

```
function transferq() {
if (document.forms[0].elements['return'].checked == true) {
document.forms[0].elements['returnhour'].disabled = false
document.forms[0].elements['returnminute'].disabled = false
document.forms[0].elements['returnday'].disabled = false
document.forms[0].elements['returnmonth'].disabled = false
document.forms[0].elements['returnyear'].disabled = false
document.forms[0].elements['returnflight'].disabled = false
document.forms[0].elements['samereturn'].disabled = false
}
}

<input name="return" id="return" type="checkbox" value="return" onchange="transferq()" />
```

it checks whether the 'return' checkbox is checked and if it is, it enables some further inputs in my form (they're originally disabled).

This works perfectly in Firefox and is done immediately but in IE you have to click on a white space in the document for it to be updated.

I've searched literally everywhere to find out why this happens but I couldn't find anything.

I'd appreciate it very much if anyone could help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried attaching the function to a different event? like using onclick?

```
 <input name="return" id="return" type="checkbox" value="return" onclick="transferq()" />
```

Comment: That was exactly the issue, IE didn't like 'onchange' and 'onclick' works like a charm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Change `onchange` to `onclick`. This should trigger the event as soon as the element is clicked, instead of when it "changes". As you are already checking whether or not it's checked in your event handler function, this should work in the same way.

Also note that instead of getting the checkbox in question in the function, you could pass it in using `this`:

```
<input name="return" id="return" type="checkbox" value="return" onclick="transferq(this)" />
```

And then use the reference to that element in the function:

```
function transferq(elem) {
    if (elem.checked == true) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Finally, note that while it's not necessary to have them, it's a good idea to use a semi-colon at the end of each line that should have one (each line inside your `if` statement).

Answer (score 0):

Change your field name from 'return' to something else. 'return' is a keyword in javascript, I had problems with keywords as names in html form.